# Why --> "ListPopupWindow: Could not call getMaxAvailableHeightMethod.... Using the public version"?

Tags: android, dialog, fragment

I try to make a *list popup* (named ***drop list***) window within my alertdialog in my fragment.

But after setting anchor and the adapter,  I received error saying:

***"I/ListPopupWindow: Could not call getMaxAvailableHeightMethod(View, int, boolean) on PopupWindow. Using the public version."***

How to solve this? Please help.

Below is my code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dblistview, container, false);

    final MyDBHandler dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(getActivity(), null,null,1);
    DBReader dbReader = new DBReader(getActivity());
    ListView dbListView  = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.dbListing);

    if (dbHandler.dbSelectQuery("*",null) != null){
        dbCustomAdapter dbListViewAdapter = new dbCustomAdapter(getActivity(),
                R.layout.dbadapterview, dbHandler.dbSelectQuery("*",null));
        dbListView.setAdapter(dbListViewAdapter);
        dbListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View v, int i, long l) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());

                TextView goodTV= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.goodTV);
                final ListPopupWindow droplist = new ListPopupWindow(getContext());
                droplist.setAnchorView(goodTV);

                ArrayList<String> disntictList = dbHandler.selectDisntictQuery(MyDBHandler.COLUMN_party);
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,disntictList);
                droplist.setAdapter(adapter);

                for (String item : disntictList){
                    Log.i("Item name", item);
                }

                View mView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_filterbox,null);
                mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        try {
                            droplist.show();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Height null?",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });


                builder.setCancelable(true);
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Ok clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

                builder.setView(mView);


                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();

            }
        });

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Database currently empty...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I finally got it. 
I made two mistakes:

1. For the `OnClickListener`for the `TextView`, it should be

   > **goodTV**.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()....

   instead of

   > *mView*.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()....
2. In defining my `TextView` within the `dblistView.setOnItemClickListener`. Because I am attaching my own XML layout called `mView` within the    dblistView.setOnItemClickListener, so for

   > TextView goodTV= (TextView) **mView**.findViewById(R.id.goodTV);

   instead of:

   > TextView goodTV= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.goodTV);